# Get the sum even if a column false/true

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 columns (Time and Material) and I want to sum them up.
The problem is that I only get the sum if I have data that is "True" in both of them. So if I have Time that is "True" and got only Material that is "False" I get nothing back. Pls help

```
 SELECT ((SELECT ROUND(SUM([Time]*[Price]),0)  FROM [tblTime] Y WHERE Y.[OwnerId] = <ID> AND Y.[Invoice] = 'True') 
+
(SELECT ROUND(SUM([Amount]*[Price]),0)  FROM [tblMaterial] M WHERE M.[OwnerId] = <ID> AND M.[Invoice] = 'True'))
```

Comment: Please post your table structures .Also, which database are you using .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of your fields is not `True`, you effectively get `NULL` value in this component, and when you add `NULL` and any number the result is always `NULL`.

To solve the issue, you can use function [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to make sure that if your value is `NULL` then `COALESCE` uses fallback value `0`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    (SELECT ROUND(SUM([Time]*[Price]),0)  
     FROM [tblTime] Y 
     WHERE Y.[OwnerId] = <ID> AND Y.[Invoice] = 'True')
    , 0)    -- value 0 is used only if SELECT returns NULL
+
COALESCE(
    (SELECT ROUND(SUM([Amount]*[Price]),0)  
     FROM [tblMaterial] M 
     WHERE M.[OwnerId] = <ID> AND M.[Invoice] = 'True')
    , 0)    -- value 0 is used only if SELECT returns NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works fine...maybe you aslo can help me to the sum to apper like this: 23.200 if a sum is 23200 wit no decimals :)

Comment: @Kristoffer Please avoid follow up questions in comments. Ask another question instead

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are issues with NULL

```
 SELECT (
    ISNULL(
       SELECT ROUND(SUM([Time]*[Price]),0)  
       FROM [tblTime] Y
       WHERE Y.[OwnerId] = <ID> AND Y.[Invoice] = 'True'
       , 0) 
    +
    ISNULL(
        SELECT ROUND(SUM([Amount]*[Price]),0) 
        FROM [tblMaterial] M 
        WHERE M.[OwnerId] = <ID> AND M.[Invoice] = 'True'
        , 0)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...the first answer worked fine. Take care :)